# Is there a way to determine function parameters to a shared library's exported symbols?

Tags: macos, unix, core-foundation, nm

Is there a way to determine function parameters to a shared library's exported symbols? I am investigating a private OSX framework for curiosity purposes (I'm aware of Apple store policies, etc). I can perform nm -g /path/to/library and determine all of the exported symbols, however, I am curious in determining the parameters that must be passed to these calls.

Answer (score 1):

No, that information is not present in a shared library's symbol table (or any other part of the shared library). That's why you need the header file when you compile against a library.